# MDX formatting number value to string

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have this measure called [YoY ppt (Market Share)], and the customer wants to see : "0.2 ppt" in the field. Number, one decimal place, with the string " ppt" attached. How do I obtain this?

```
    CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Market Sales % CY] AS NULL, VISIBLE = 1, Display_Folder = 'Calcs';  
SCOPE([Measures].[Market Sales % CY]);  
        This =  (([Measures].[Market Share %],[Version].[Version].&[Actual]));

END SCOPE;  

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Market Sales % PY] AS NULL, VISIBLE = 1, Display_Folder = 'Calcs';  
SCOPE([Measures].[Market Sales % PY]);  
        This = ([Measures].[Market Share %],[Version].[Version].&[Actual PY]); 

END SCOPE;


CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[YoY ppt (Market Share)] AS NULL, VISIBLE = 1;
SCOPE([Measures].[YoY ppt (Market Share)]);  
        This = CASE WHEN ISEMPTY([Measures].[Market Sales % PY]) OR ISEMPTY([Measures].[Market Sales % CY]) THEN NULL 
ELSE ([Measures].[Market Sales % CY] * 100 - [Measures].[Market Sales % PY] * 100)
END;
    --FORMAT_STRING(This) = "Percent";    
FORMAT_STRING(This) = "Fixed"; -- to be changed to "0.0 ppt"
END SCOPE;
```

Comment: what is wrong with the format_string you have "0.0 ppt" ?

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: how about "0.0 \p\p\t" ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[YoY ppt (Market Share)] AS NULL
, VISIBLE = 1;

SCOPE([Measures].[YoY ppt (Market Share)]);
This = 
   CASE WHEN ISEMPTY([Measures].[Market Sales % PY]) 
             OR ISEMPTY([Measures].[Market Sales % CY]) THEN NULL 
   ELSE ([Measures].[Market Sales % CY] * 100 - [Measures].[Market Sales % PY] * 100)
   END;
END SCOPE;  

SCOPE([Measures].[YoY ppt (Market Share)]); 
FORMAT_STRING(this) = "0.0 \p\p\t";
END SCOPE;
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is still recognized as a number. I wonder if it´s possible at all to convert this number measure to a text? Customer wants to see "0.1 ppt" in the pivot table field and not "0.1".

Comment: @KatalinPap they might have "Preseve Cell Formatting" selected in the pivot options?